# Unable to get count increment if two arrays have same elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I am trying to get a count for candidates that appear on both array for each event_id. This is what I tried.

```
$temp = array();

foreach ( $events as $event)
{
    foreach ( $users as $user )
    {
        if ( $event['event_id'] ==  $user['event_id'] )
        {
            $temp [$event['event_id']] = 0;

            if ( $event['user_id'] ==  $user['user_id'] )
            {
                $temp [$event['event_id']]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get. Everything is 0 even though there are users that appear on both arrays for the same event_id.

```
array (size=15)
  384 => int 0
  395 => int 0
  392 => int 0
  404 => int 0
  406 => int 0
  313 => int 0
  315 => int 0
  322 => int 0
  326 => int 0
  327 => int 0
  334 => int 0
  717 => int 0
  344 => int 0
  378 => int 0
  403 => int 0
```

Comment: Try moving `$temp [$event['event_id']] = 0;` to immediately after the first loop starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting `$temp [$event['event_id']]` to 0 on each iteration in which `event_id` matches in both arrays.

You need to set `$temp [$event['event_id']]` to 0 only once, Like this:

```
$temp = array();

foreach ( $events as $event)
{
    $temp [$event['event_id']] = 0;
    foreach ( $users as $user )
    {
        if ( $event['event_id'] ==  $user['event_id'] && $event['user_id'] ==  $user['user_id'] )
        { 
            $temp [$event['event_id']]++;
        }
    }
}
```